# What shapes do these quotients represent? Do they have a name?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

I am unable to visualize complex shapes in space. I can draw simpler shapes and explain which points correspond to which but can't for the life of me determine the name of the shape. I would like somebody to help me identify those. I will present my thought process through a picture since it is very difficult to explain with words.

I am given the quotients $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times[0,1]/\sim$ where $\sim$ denotes $(t,0) \sim (-t,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times[0,1]/\sim'$ where $\sim'$ denotes $(t,0) \sim (t,1)$.

I think the first quotient represents a cylinder whose opposite edges at extremities are "identified", i.e. it looks kind of a Möbius strip but I don't think it is the Möbius strip because of instead of having sides as extremities there are circles. I have made a drawing to see things better but I still can't identify the correct shape. Maybe some kind of 8-looking strip that's not Möbius?

The second one seems easier and I guess it's just the torus... Am I right?

For the first one:

[image]

if I try to "identify" the circles in my head I just get some kind of strip that intersects itself like an "8" strip. Does this shape have a name? I have low spatial IQ

Comment: This is better known as the Klein bottle. It has no boundary.

Comment: @MikeMiller I did look at the Klein bottle before posting, but still couldn't see how circles were oppositely-identified. Now that I know the answer, I see it. (I didn't pay enough attention to the fact that the "bend" essentially makes this cross-identification I couldn't put my finger on...) Well thank you, I guess this qualifies as an answer, however short...

Comment: I would have drawn pictures if I had the capability :) Maybe you will be able to do so and post an answer. I would upvote.

Comment: @MikeMiller A Klein bottle on paint will look like no Klein bottle, might as well quote or link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle, still I can't answer my own question if somebody else just gave me the answer